# C++, OpenCV, TrayTracing: invalid initialization of reference of type math::float3b&

Tags: c++, reference, raytracing

im trying to call this function

```
bool intersectRaySphere(const float3& p, const float3& d, const float3& c, 
float r, float& t)
{

}
```

from this functin using a double loop

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> ray_direction;

    for (int y = 0; y < height(framebuffer); ++y)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width(framebuffer); ++x)
        {
            float ray_dir_x = (x/width(framebuffer) - 0,5) * w_s;
            float ray_dir_y = (y/height(framebuffer) - 0,5) * w_s;
            float ray_dir_z = (y * -1);
            std::vector<float> ray_direction;

            ray_direction.push_back(ray_dir_x);
            ray_direction.push_back(ray_dir_y);
            ray_direction.push_back(ray_dir_z);
            float3& lv_c = ray_direction;
}
```

But im unsure how to declare the parameters for function bool intersectRaySphere(). I know the first parameter p is the address of a vector. So im creating the vector in my main with three values but im not sure how to pass this one correctly to the function where i would need it to work with it.

I tried it in different ways - with this way here i got the message "invalid initialization of reference of type math::float3b&". Would really appreciate some tipps how to do this correctly...

Robert

Comment: The first parameter is not a vector. It's a `const float3&`. How exactly are you trying to call that function? Your code doesn't show the call.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Im trying to call the function like this: intersectRaySphere(camera_basis, lv_c, c, r, t); So the idea would be to create a 3D Vector and use it for const float& p in the function... do you have a suggestion how to handle this correctly?

Comment: You can't cast from `std::vector` to `const float&`. Why are you using a vector when you need an array? There are two declarations for `std::vector<float> ray_direction;` in different scopes. The error message comes from the line `float3& lv_c = ray_direction;`.